# Getting user view information

Tags: python, bokeh

Is it somehow possible to get information about the view of the user on my bokeh plot?

One can adjust the initial view on the plot, but when the user zooms in or out the dimensions change. Let's say I want to plot the function y=x^2, in the default view plotting it for x from -5 to 5 with 100 samples is sufficient. But if the user zooms in the line gets very coarse and inaccurate. Now it would be better to resample the function and get 100 samples from -1 to 1. The same goes vice versa for zooming out:

This is nice:

[image: nice view]

This is not nice (having samples going from something like -30 to 30 would be better):

[image: no nice view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get user view information by accessing

```
plot = Figure(title="some Figure",x_range=[-1,1],y_range=[-1,1])
plot.x_range.__getattribute__('start')
plot.y_range.__getattribute__('start')
plot.x_range.__getattribute__('end')
plot.y_range.__getattribute__('end')
```

Now you can either explicitly update your plot using a refresh button. Or add a periodic callback

```
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(refresh, 100)
```

,which calls the function

```
refresh()
```

all 100 milliseconds. See http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/bokeh/bokeh-notebooks/blob/master/tutorial/08%20-%20server.ipynb for an example on periodic callback.